# Can't adjust height in image

Tags: html, wordpress, image, css

The code:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
<img src="https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/satou.jpg" style="height:100%;" alt="satou" />
Match for the newborn son of Marialena Satou, 3/4/2016. Wish him health! :)
</div>
```

The result in my [site](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B2%CE%B9/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%B2%CE%AF-history-description/).

Without the styling, it will be the same:

[image]

I would like to reduce the height of the picture. What am I missing here?

Comment: You want 50% of what?

Comment: Of the original size @Shomz, I followed the example of w3schools.

Comment: It doesn't quite work like that (it's actually based on the parent's height when used like that) - read this from a more credible source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height

Comment: Hmm, how would you do it then @Shomz? Thanks for the info btw!

Comment: No problem, man. Hmm, you need a different logic, not depending on the input image size (it makes no sense to use 50% of the external element size, right?), but rather suit it to what you're building. Do you have external image size convention or something? Why not just specify height in pixels?

Comment: No. I think I should manually play around in terms of pixels, thank you! Are you going to post an answer, or should I delete the question @Shomz?

Comment: I think you can delete it, because the answer is more a concept change rather than a programming solution. You're welcome! :) Just don't forget that when you switch to image dimension in percentages, it related to the image parent, not the image (the file) resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to give your picture height 480px because you original size is 960px.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `img` with a `span` or `div`:

```
<span class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="...">
</span>
```

And then style those two elements:

```
.img-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    width: 50%; 
}
```

Setting the width to 50% will also resize the height to 50%.

Comment: Thanks R. Smith, nice idea!